# nginx https can not connect via ie

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, internet-explorer

I installed nginx and set up https. When I connect to the web server over https using chrome or opera it works. When I connect using ie and edge over https I get the message "This page can’t be displayed";

```
set ssl
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam4096.pem;
```

my nginx.conf and istyle.conf
http://istyle.kr/nginx.conf
http://istyle.kr/istyle.conf

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: What operating system are the client and server? Does curl work from the local machine or a remote machine? Give us more information, including logs like Michael said

Comment: Can you paste the conf inline? Downloading files from unknown sources where I'm asked to identify myself with a certificate isn't exactly calming. @user160153

Answer (score 1):

**Browser Compatibility with TLS Configuration**

When in doubt, point [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) at your site.  Be sure to check the box to hide results, so your domain does not show up on their list of recently tested sites.

They also have a [DEV Qualys TLS Server Test](https://dev.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) that includes additional tests.

Both will show you a list of user agents and versions that will be able to connect to your site and using what SSL Protocol.

Comment: im so strange.. caz... all browser work except windows 10 IE and EDGE.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your config with the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) might be that IE doesn't like your cipher list.

Comment: Thx.....but... hmmm...not work.